# isNull(NULL +" and"," on") return " and" in PHP MSSQL

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, xampp

Why `'select isNull(NULL +" and"," on")'` returns `"on"` in sql server but its return `" and"` in php mssql?
while directly executing the query in sql server it returns `" on"`.

But using PHP [ mssql_quey] it returns `" and"`.

I need `" on"`.

```
PHP v 5.3 
Xampp v3 
MS SQL Server 2008
```

Not: I Tried `COALESCE(NULL + ' and', ' on')` ..same problem

Comment: Your php code is relevent here.  Edit your question and add it.

Comment: $query="select ISNULL(NULL+ ' and',' no')";
$res=mssql_query($query);
$data=mssql_fetch_row($res);
var_dump($data);  Actually there is a trigger in mssql,which having that ISNULL function, while execute that its from php its showing  "Syntax error near 'and' ",but using asp.net or directly execute sql server execute correctly

Answer (score 0):

try this
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON

Comment: I found this to work with specific tables only. YOu have to play around with the following combinations: SELECT PKCols = COALESCE(PKCols + ' and', ' on') OR SELECT PKCols = COALESCE(PKCols + ' on', ' on') with SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON; set or not

Answer (score 0):

You are probably facing the problem with NULL value passing. At least, it looks that way as asp.net works ok.

I suggest you to try to substitute expression with null-valued variable like:

```
declare @test varchar(10); select isNull(@test + " and"," on")
```